# What bad can do following php code?

Tags: php, xss

I need help in understanding `XSS` on `PHP`. Which security holes are in this specific case?

```
<?php
$test = NULL;
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];

if(!$test){
    die("$name cannot be found");
}

?>
```

EDITED. WHY IT SHOW ME PHPINFO? LINK http://testing985.freeiz.com/

```
<?
$test = NULL;
$name = ''.print phpinfo().'';

if(!$test){
    die("$name cannot be found");
}
?>
```

Comment: Uh... that won't do anything at all except `die`.

Comment: Show us something where you're doing something with `$name` and we may be able to show you where the XSS exploit is. Otherwise this question has no substance.

Comment: Run it in the address bar like `index.php?name=<script>alert('haha! got you!');</script>` and you'll see

Comment: Lets say that $name = "".print '<b>HELLO</b>'."";   OUTPUT: <b>HELLO</b>1 cannot be found

Comment: @user3524402 from what you've shown, it doesn't _matter_ what `$name` equals. What matters is _what you do with it_.

Comment: What if $name = ''.print phpinfo().''; it shows me phpinfo

Answer (score 1):

Enter this and you will see:

```
index.php?name=%3Cscript%20type%3D%22text%2Fjavascript%22%3E%0Awindow.location.href%20%3D%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.de%22%3B%0A%3C%2Fscript%3E
```

In this example you go to google. In real world you would go to a phishing site, which look exactly the same, like  your page.

To santize this, you want to remove tags for example:

```
$name = strip_tags($name);
```

Alternative there is a more powerfull framework availibe:

http://htmlpurifier.org/

Also this here:

```
$name = "''.print phpinfo().''";
```

Will ourput this:

```
''.print phpinfo().'' cannot be found
```

The reason is, that `''.print phpinfo().''` is already a `string`. You would need to `eval($name);` to get it executed. Better you forget `eval` immediately.

Also note:

```
$test = NULL;

if (!$test){}; //true
if ($test){}; //false
if ($test === false){}; //false
if ($test === true){}; //false
if ($test === null){}; //true
```

**For your edit:**

My bad, with the line `$name = ''.print phpinfo().''` i meant, if you have a url like this `index.php?name=%27%27.print%20phpinfo().%27%27%3B` which basicly stands for `$name = "''.print phpinfo().''"` instead of `$name = ''.print phpinfo().''`.

Means:

If I want to enter for your `$name` the code `''.print phpinfo().'';`, i would escape it to `%27%27.print%20phpinfo().%27%27%3B`.

Now you have this line:

```
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
```

You write the content of the GET VAR (In this case `''.print phpinfo().'';`) as `string` into your `$name`

So your basicly have this line:

```
$name = "''.print phpinfo().''";
```

And this will output simple:

```
''.print phpinfo().''
```

So why this line gives the PHP Info Output?

```
$name = ''.print phpinfo().'';
```

It are 3 parts:

- `''` (returns empty String)
- `print phpinfo()` (returns `1` from print; The print command doeas nothing, since `phpinfo()` return `void`; `phpinfo()` does his job and output at this points the Information)
- `''` (returns empty String)

So you assign your `$name` a string chain of `Nothing`, `1`, `Nothing`. This means, `$name = '1'`. In this assignment, you already have printed the `phpinfo()`.

With this line:

```
die("$name cannot be found");
```

You append to the already Info output, the text `1 cannnot be found`;